# Connection to sql server express with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, sql-server-express

I'm new to .net and c# and want to connect Sql server express available in visual studio 2010.
I have searched a lot and read connection strings in [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) but still don't know how to connect.
i added a "service-based database" with adding new item and now have a **db.mdf** with tables.

my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class First
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=db2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();


            Console.WriteLine("ok");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

but it does not connect. in fact it executes with no errors , but no output for *Console.WriteLine("ok");*

how should be the connection-string in my case? specially for "Data source". I don't know what should its value be. please tell me the full connection-string which suits my case.

I'm really new to .net and confused many days for a simple connection.

also tried many other connection strings , but not working...

Comment: What do you mean by "does not connect"? What do you expect?

Comment: 1- i run queries and it does not return any result . 2- no output for the code above

Comment: there is no where you told your code to return anything from the db. Are you just learning?

Comment: it should output "ok" if code runs ok. but now by *Candie* answer , it works right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
{



}
```

Comment: first of all gives an error for the backslash : "unrecognized escape string"

Comment: Try double backslash "\\" or "@" (literal string), before the string.

Comment: sorry. i'm able to only read data from db. and insert,update and delete not working. is there any permission issue? how to solve it?

Comment: i don't think but you can just verify and validate your query